# Group values returned from db

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Using var_dump, i have this array from query:
[image]

But if you look, there are several arrays, where value of the TRM_HORA_INICIO field are the same. I was wondering if it is possible to reorder this. Something like:  [image]

My idea is: group all arrays containing the TRM_HORA_INICIO field with same value in an array.
Because i have several other arrays where the field in question has different values. Something like: 11:00, 12:00, etc...

Can anyone help me with this? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach($query_result as $element){
    $result[$element['TRM_HORA_INICIO']][] = $element;
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.